# How to save fields of object into database using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, orm

I'm trying to make my own ORM framework. I get the values from object into arrayList and I'm trying to save them in one time. I have to make for loop to save them all, but I'm confused how to make it?

```
prepareteState = connect.prepareStatement(Query);
for (int y = 1; y <= obs.size()  ; y++) {
    for(Object obj : obs){
        prepareteState.setObject(y, obj);
        System.out.println(Query);
        System.out.println(prepareteState.toString());
    }
}
prepareteState.execute();
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but if you can't use JDBC and don't know how to use loops in Java, why the hell are you making yet a new ORM framework? That's like wanting to climb the Everest when you can't even walk yet.

Comment: i know how to make loops and how to use jdbc. the problem in that wnen i have entity whit 5 columns and i save values from this columns in arraylist how to save them in 1 time setting "insert into tableName values (?,?,?,?,?,?) ? :)

Comment: If you knew how to use loops, you wouldn't have two nested loops iterating on the same list, one of them going from 1 to size instead of 0 to size - 1. If you knew how to use JDBC, you would know how to prepare a statement, bind parameters, and call executeUpdate() on the statement. Read the Java tutorials. They have one on [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) and one on [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).

Comment: I don`t want to be rude but, this is just an not formated example and this for loop start from 1 because parameters in jdbc starts from 1 not from 0 :)

Comment: So does your list contain a list of objects with attributes or does your list just contain all attributes of one object?

Comment: So, why don't you show us a real, well-formatted example of code, respecting Java naming conventions, instead of the above which doesn't make any sense? We could at least start from someting. Otherwise, all we can do is tell you to read the official tutorial (which you should do anyway).

Comment: list contains all attributes of one object.I`m trying to set them to PrepeareStatement. I think maybe i should set them one by one into String and make Query using Statement instead of PrepareStatement ? What do you think "home" or maybe there is better solution using PrepareStatement ?

Comment: Have you read the tutorial? How about `int i = 0; for (Object param : parameters) {preparedStatement.setObject(i + 1, param); i++}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for good advices but, i found the solution :) it is a little bit different than the first idea but, works fine for me:) instead of using prepareState and setObject one by one i`m using StringBuilder to make String and execute query

```
private String makeInsertQuery(List<String> listOfColumnsNames, List<Object> listOfParameters, String tableName){
    StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder();
    String query = null;

    if(listOfColumnsNames != null && listOfColumnsNames.size() != 0 && listOfParameters != null && listOfParameters.size() != 0 && tableName != null){
        for(String string : listOfColumnsNames){
            columns.append(string + ",");
        }
        columns.deleteCharAt(columns.length() - 1);

        for(Object object : listOfParameters){
            parameters.append ("'" + object + "'" + ",");
        }
        parameters.deleteCharAt(parameters.length() - 1);

        query = "INSERT " + "INTO " + tableName +  " ( " + columns.toString() + " ) " + " VALUES " + "( " + parameters.toString() + " )" ; 
    }
    //TODO if you need check for null 
    return query;
}
```